# Implementing a skewed assosiative data cache C++

Tags: c++, caching, architecture

Can someone help me on how to go about writing a program for (say 3-way) skewed data cache?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Choose three hash functions (first one should probably be the trivial one which is mod (%) cache size)
2. Make an array
3. Each new cache line should be hashed by each of those three hash functions
4. Evict one of the lines indicated by those hashes
5. Replace it with your new line
6. Repeat

The C++ for this should be pretty trivial, but I don't know which hash functions you want to use.

Comment: I've been looking for an excuse to use this for something: http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/04/introducing-cityhash.html

Comment: If he's caching things indexed by strings, then those would probably work well.  If they're indexed by numbers, probably not so much.